# Why is my nested if/else statement not working in my PHP/html script?

Tags: php, html, ping

I am trying to make a quick PHP script that is accessible from through an html form.  The idea is for the user to input a url, the PHP script should ping the url, and echo back success or fail.  I have Apache on a linux mint machine, and am testing though //localhost. 
within PHP, I am using PEAR’s Net_Ping package.

The script work fine on the command line when I hard code a url to ping, but when I write it into an html form the if else statement fails.

When I input a url for the script to ping, it wil echo back "ping was successful"
If I disable my internet to test the else statement, it will still echo back "ping was successful"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    require("Net/Ping.php");
    $ping = Net_Ping::factory();

    if ($_POST["url"]) {
        $result = $ping->ping($_POST["url"]);
        if ($result) {
            echo "ping was successful\n";
        } else {
            echo "ping was unsuccessful\n";
        } 
    }
?>
<html>
<body>
<p>This is a free web based URL ping service</p>
<p>Input your favorite URL and see if China is blocking it today!</P>
<form action="<?php test33.php ?>" method="POST">
URL: <input type="text" name="url" /> 
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `action="<?php test33.php ?>"` doesn't look correct, get rid of the php tags.

Comment: Error output might be disabled by environment. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` before `require("Net/Ping.php")`, so that you will not miss any errors/warnings.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
<form action="<?php test33.php ?>" method="POST">
```

It should be:

```
<form action="test33.php" method="POST">
```

or:

```
<form action="<?php echo "test33.php"; ?>" method="POST">
```

or:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
```

so you don't have to hard-code the script name. You could also leave it blank, since it defaults to the current URL:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    require("Net/Ping.php");
    $ping = Net_Ping::factory();

    if ($_POST["url"]) {
        $result = $ping->ping($_POST["url"]);
        if ($result) {
            echo "ping was successful\n";
        } else {
            echo "ping was unsuccessful\n";
        } 
    }
?>
<html>
<body>
<p>This is a free web based URL ping service</p>
<p>Input your favorite URL and see if China is blocking it today!</P>
<form action="" method="POST">
URL: <input type="text" name="url" /> 
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Your form action="" has a problem. It submitted in another page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `<?php` `tag` in the `Form` You have to use it like this;

- Use `echo`
- Use the file name in the quete. Else php will assume that as contant.

Your `form` `action` is like this `action="<?php test33.php ?>";` in here `test33.php` is with out `quete`

use the `quete` around it. Like this

```
<form action="<?php echo "test33.php" ?>" method="POST">
```

Edited part. According to the doc, `ping` return `error array` if `url` is empty, Thats means your `$result` is never going to be false. So your code never going to run `else` statement. To solve this 
use `!empty` in your `if` statement.

Like this

```
if (!empty($_POST["url"])) {
        $result = $ping->ping($_POST["url"]);
        if ($result) {
            echo "ping was successful\n";
        } else {
            echo "ping was unsuccessful\n";
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think because your `$_POST['url']` hasn't yet initialize. You have to check in your `if` statement it is exists or not

```
if (isset($_POST["url"] && $_POST["url"])
```

Comment: An uninitialized variable is falsy, so the `if` will do the right thing. You'll just get a warning about using an undefined index.